# how to export mutiple page attachements in xwiki 9.7

Tags: xwiki

i am working on xwiki 9.7,i have created multiple pages but when i am exporting those pages images are not shown in that pdf.

like this "ServerName/xwiki/bin/export/WikiSpace/WikiPage?format=xar&pages=WikiSpace.WikiPage&pages=Sandbox.ProjectTest
&pages=Managers.Leaders&pages=XWiki.MyDashboard"

i am exporting multiple pages

Comment: Note that your URL is not correct since you mentioned PDF and you used `format=xar` but I guess that's a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have found a bug. Would you mind reporting it at http://jira.xwiki.org/browse/XWIKI so that it can get fixed?

Note that I think I've found some more info about it. If I call the following URL `http://localhost:8080/xwiki/bin/export/Sandbox/WebHome?format=pdf`(or `http://localhost:8080/xwiki/bin/export/Sandbox/WebHome?format=pdf&pages=Sandbox.WebHome`), then the image appears fine.

However if I call `http://localhost:8080/xwiki/bin/export/A/B?format=pdf&pages=Sandbox.WebHome` then the image doesn't appear. So it seems to be a context issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer for exporting the image in case of multiple page ,instead of adding the image give the URL of that image then it will work fine for multiple page export